# "having been done” and “done”

Tags: passive-voice

> No one can walk the wire without a bit of fear unless trained very young.
>
> No one can walk the wire without a bit of fear unless **having been** trained very young.

Both "having been done" and "done" can indicate passivity and completion of an action, so why is the former one correct？

Answer (score 8):

The first sentence simply omits the verb *to be* because the meaning is clear without it. You could say "unless they were trained very young".

Personally, I think "unless they have been trained very young" sounds better than "unless having been".

Comment: Omit to be？Do you mean that the original sentence is "... unless to be trained"？ I think "to be" indicates future.

Comment: No, I said 'the verb _to be_', not 'the words _to be'_. **They were** is the past tense of _to be._

Comment: Thank you! It is a brand-new idea to me. haha

Comment: @庄怀玉: I don't agree with this answer for the same reason as for *gotube*'s answer, but this answer is not as bad. Unlike the other answer, this one does not claim that the grammatical function of "unless" makes only the second sentence wrong. The error in this answer is that it failed to consider the temporal relation between the participle and the noun that it modifies. Please see my answer for the correct analysis.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't find your answer below. Besides, can anyone tell me how to @ people...

Comment: Typing '@' followed by the first letter of the person's username should bring up a list of the people contributing to the discussion whose names begin with that letter; you can then click on the one you want. (I don't know how it works with a name in Chinese characters!)

Answer (score 5):

The word "unless" is a *conjunction* that joins two *clauses* together. The phrase "having been trained very young" isn't a clause, so it cannot come after "unless", so the second sentence is ungrammatical.

The first sentence is correct because the word "trained" in that context is understood to be a reduced form of "they were trained", which is a clause, so it can follow "unless".

If you want to use "having been trained", "having" is a gerund, which is a noun, so you need a preposition in the place of "unless". "Without" is a preposition with roughly the same meaning:

> No one can walk the wire without a bit of fear **without** having been trained very young.

Repeating "without" twice in the same sentence is poor style, but the grammar and meaning are good.

Comment: When he was looking for a job, he run into an old classmate. This sentence can be changed into "when looking for a job,  ..."

Comment: If the sentence is "... unless they have been trained", why can't it be written as "unless having been trained"

Comment: You are wrong. The second sentence is correct, while the first is incorrect!

Comment: @user21820 Can you explain why you think so?

Comment: @庄怀玉 Those reduced forms mostly work when the elided verb is a "*be*" verb, like "was" in your example. It usually `doesn't work with other verbs like "have".

Comment: @gotube: I have explained why I think so in my answer. Your answer is completely wrong and I don't understand why you don't get it. Probably it's for the reason that I gave to Colin, namely that many native speakers have trouble with the rarely used grammatical constructions. In fact, I know many native speakers who don't even use participle phrases...

Comment: My teacher once mentioned the idea  of ellipsis. I wonder if the omission of "he was" in "when looking for a job" and "they were" in "unless they were trained" are the same matter of omission. and both of the two sentences can attest to your answer that conjunction can connect two sentence or clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the present perfect "have/has done", constructions with a form of *have* followed by a past participle are always looking back on an event from some later point of time.

If there is no particular later time to focus on, there is no point in using such constructions - and in fact English speakers often do not bother to use them when they could, if the temporal relationships are clear without.

So in your example, there is no time in the past (later than the training) from which the training is being viewed, so using the "having been trained" construction is unnecessary and awkward.

A context in which you might use such a construction is *Having been trained very young to walk the wire, I felt little fear when I did so*. The viewpoint is the time when I did walk the wire, and the training is being viewed from that time.

Comment: Thank you！I think the action of being trained should precede the action of walking the wire. According to your answer, there is no particular time, so I should use the more simple -ed.

Comment: While it is true that many native speakers drop words from the standard grammatical structures, (1) just sounds wrong to anyone who is used to speaking perfect English. I have attempted to explain why in my post. Ironically, your last paragraph supports my analysis, because it would be completely wrong to say "Trained very young to walk the wire, I felt little fear when I did so.".